# NoMethodError for has_many :though (undefined method class_name for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently ran into a *NoMethodError* when I call any method on `organization.subscriptions`

```
NoMethodError at /organizations/1
undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  class_eval
```

It looks like class_name is called on something that doesn't exist. But since there are a deal and a subscription this shouldn't happen. I've been staring at my code but I can't see the mistake. Can anybody help?

```
# organization.rb
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deals
  has_many :subscriptions, through: :deals, source: :initialized_subscriptions
end

# deal.rb
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :initialized_subscriptions, foreign_key: :initial_deal_id, class_name: 'Subscription'
end

# subscription.rb
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :initial_deal, class_name: 'Deal'
end
```

Here are the tables

```
organizations    
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Org name |
+----+----------+

deals
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id |    name    | organization_id |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | First Deal |               1 |
+----+------------+-----------------+

subscriptions
+----+-----------------+
| id | initial_deal_id |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |               1 |
+----+-----------------+
```

Thanks so much for the help, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a blind shot, but I think Rails assumes a different class name in your `has_many` association.

```rb
# In this case, Rails assumes class_name: 'Subscription'
has_many :subscriptions
```

```rb
# In this case, Rails also assumes class_name: 'Subscription'
has_many :subscriptions, through: :deals
```

```rb
# But in this case, I think Rails assumes class_name: 'InitializedSubscription'
has_many :subscriptions, through: :deals, source: :initialized_subscriptions
```

Maybe try this

```rb
has_many :subscriptions, through: :deals,
                         source: :initialized_subscriptions,
                         class_name: 'Subscription'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Though Rails infers the class name from the association name, so ```subscriptions``` becomes ```Subscription```.
```source``` shouldn't have an effect on the ```class_name```.

Comment: Your hint with ```class_name``` pushed me in the right direction though. I have another ```has_many :through``` association declared in the ```Subscription``` model. Apparently Rails couldn't infer ```Deal``` from ```:deals``` there. Not sure why.